# Convert Array of Integers to ArrayDeque Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraydeque

How can I to convert Array of Integers to ArrayDeque? For example, instead to add numbers in ArrayDeque with loop, will I can to convert this Array of integers directly to ArrayDeque? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Arrays.stream(1,2,3,4,5).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new))`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You need to call `boxed` on the `IntStream` before you can `collect` this way.

Answer (score 8):

```
 List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
 ArrayDeque<Integer> ad = new ArrayDeque<>(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array into a `List` first, preserving values type casting. Then create a `Deque` from a `List`.

```
int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
// List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(array);
List<Integer> array = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Deque<Integer> arrayDeque = new ArrayDeque<>(array);
```